# SQL server round down wit 0.5 step

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like round down decimal value with 0.5 step:

example:

```
 declare @value = 6.7

round (@value, 1, 2) as new
```

all values should be:

```
if 6.7 should return 6.5
if 6.9 should return 6.5
if 6.4 should return 6 etc.
```